# Dynamic Compilation of ASP.NET Page?

Tags: asp.net

How can I achieve this? I am trying to load content from the database and fuse it together with the Content control. The progrm is some of the content has dynamic bits to it and thus would like it to be compiled on the fly. Has anyone done this sort of stuff before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what you really need to do here?

If the content is dynamic, generate the controls for it at run time based on the data. If you then need to improve the performance, why not cache the page output?

AFAIK there would be no real benefit to dynamic compilation based on what you seem to be doing.

Try these links:

- [HOW TO: Dynamically Create Controls in ASP.NET with Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317515) - obviously VB, but porting to C# should be no big deal.
- [Output Caching in ASP.NET 2.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513215155/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/121306-1.aspx)